# Get Async Data in Nuxt.js Component

Tags: asynchronous, coffeescript, fetch, nuxt.js

> Code snippets are written in Pug and Coffeescript

---

I know about asyncData and it limitations, but what the best practice to get async data from component in Nuxt.js ?

I write some logic in my page, but it's obviously not acceptable since I have cards more than two.

```
asyncData: ->
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.github.com/repos/username'
    { data: repo1 } = await axios '/repo1'
    { data: repo4 } = await axios '/repo4'
    { data: repo8 } = await axios '/repo8'
    { data: repo18 } = await axios '/repo18'
    {
      repo1:
        stargazers: repo1.stargazers_count
        description: repo1.description
        url: repo1.html_url
      repo4:
        stargazers: repo4.stargazers_count
        description: repo4.description
        url: repo4.html_url
      repo8:
        stargazers: repo8.stargazers_count
        description: repo8.description
        url: repo8.html_url
      repo18:
        stargazers: repo18.stargazers_count
        description: repo18.description
        url: repo18.html_url
    }
```

```
CardSlot(
      title='repo1'
      :subtitle='repo1.description'
      :titleLink='repo1.url'
    )
     h1 {{repo1.stargazers}}
CardSlot(
      title='repo4'
      :subtitle='repo4.description'
      :titleLink='repo4.url'
    )
     h1 {{repo4.stargazers}}
CardSlot(
      title='repo8'
      :subtitle='repo8.description'
      :titleLink='repo8.url'
    )
     h1 {{repo8.stargazers}}
CardSlot(
      title='repo18'
      :subtitle='repo18.description'
      :titleLink='repo18.url'
    )
     h1 {{repo18.stargazers}}
```

I want to write only:

```
CardSlot(
      title='repo1'
)
CardSlot(
      title='repo4'
)
CardSlot(
      title='repo8'
)
CardSlot(
      title='repo18'
)
```

and inside CardSlot component all data magic will happen

---

### add #3: Final push!

so now all I need — is to pass it to the props\slots somehow 
in terms of `asyncData`

```
asyncData: ({ params }) ->
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.github.com/repos/username'
    repo = 'repo22'
    res = await axios('/' + repo)
    {
      stargazers: res.data.stargazers_count
      description: res.data.description
      url: res.data.html_url
    }
...

      h1 {{description}}
```

I guess I need to define an array, so therefore data can be fetched in a loop, before page loads, and after to pass it somehow to the cards slots

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your questions !

please could you reformulated it.

but if you want to get many data in one request you could do this =>

```
 export default {
  async asyncData ({ params }) {
   let users  = await axios.get(`https://api/users/`)
   let friends  = await axios.get(`https://my-api/friends`)
   return { 
        users: users.data
        friends: friends.data
     }
 }
}
```

according to the docs https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data

Thanks !

Comment: Nice idea! But not exactly what I need.

I have few endpoints (repo1, repo2, ... repo20) in my main username repo, so I want to define only the name of the end point(repo5, repo9, repo18), which will grab all the relevant data and be displayed on my card.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: No PUG nor Cofeescript :)

Can you make your component dynamic? Inside pages/ create a page called `_repo.vue`

Now this repo component will have a property in `$route.params.repo`.

So your asyncData looks like:

```
asyncData({route}) {
   const data = await axios `https://api.github.com/repos/username/${route.params.repo}`

  return data
}
```

That should work.

Comment: It's not a page, it's just a card =)

Comment: So you want to show a card for each repo you have on the same page with the same URL?

Comment: **Borjante** — exactly ! And my main struggle that I can't parametrize data grabbing logic in component level, meanwhile in page level it is becoming a boilerplate. I updated OP post, so it looks now a little more obvious

Answer (score 0):

`asyncData` just confused me, so I ended up in wrong place, trying to solve unnecessary problems, I realized now — it is completely not suitable for my purposes, so I rework it with plain old vue'ish `created` function:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .div(
    :created="axiSync"
  )
    h3 asyComp2
    h1 {{statusText}}
    h1 {{status}}
    h3 {{stargazersCount}}
    h3 {{description}}
    h3 {{htmlUrl}}
    h3 {{ratelimit}}
</template>
<script lang="coffee">
import axios from 'axios'
export default
  props: ['repo']
  data: ->
    statusText: ''
    status: ''
    stargazersCount: ''
    description: ''
    htmlUrl: ''
    ratelimit: ''
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/userName/'
  methods:
    axiSync: ->
      response = await axios.get(@url + @repo)
      @statusText = response.statusText
      @status = response.status
      @stargazersCount = response.data.stargazers_count
      @description = response.data.description
      @htmlUrl = response.data.html_url
      @ratelimit = response.headers['x-ratelimit-remaining']
 </script>

...

asyComp2(
      repo = 'niceAndDandy'
    )
```

Thank you to everyone! ^_^